# api access token post request, where to start

Tags: google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

I've been struggling learning Auth for several months now, it comes down to I don't know where to start, it seems there are a bunch of different methods.

I am using an API that provides a token called "Personal Access Token".
Does this mean it's a Bearer or Web Token? I'm lost with this terminology.

They allow you to play with their API in their online tools.  I am making a POST request.

The api provides this info:

Link to send Post Request: www.hackerrank.com/restoflink

**Request Headers:**

```
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": 190
}
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "username": "testing",
    "subject": "test",
    "message": "test",
    "send_email": "true",
    "force": "false",
    "hide_login_credentials": "true",
    "access_token": "Access Token Number"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
function onFormSubmission(e){
  var accessToken ="ACCESS_TOKEN";

  var options = {

    method: "post",  
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },

    payload: {
      "username": "testing@gmail.com",
      "subject": "test",
      "message": "test",
      "send_email": "true",
      "force": "false",
      "hide_login_credentials": "true",
      "access_token": "ACCESS TOKEN",
      "muteHttpExceptions": "false",
      "contentType": "application/json"
    }


  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("linkhere", options);


  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());  

}
```

When I run this code without the bearer token in the header, I get a "404 truncated server error, "Invalid Access Token"".

This is why I include the token in the in header ("I'm guessing it is a Bearer Token)

The response I get from the request is 200 but it doesn't perform the action I expect it to.

I'm confused on what adjustment I have to make, even though I'm getting at 200 response code, something isn't working with my request from Apps Script.

I tried making the request from POSTMAN and the api's test tools and all my attempts worked, which makes me believe I am doing something wrong in my script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, [this post already helped out a lot](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/debugging-external-host-communication-with-urlfetchapp/)!

Comment: The term "Personal Access Token" doesn't have any specific meaning, which make searching for this kind of stuff difficult.  If you provide a link to the API documentation that would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, here's the link to their docs, I'm using the first link on the page "hacker rank for work v2" http://apidocs.hackerrank.com/

Comment: I believe it is an "OAuth 2" Access Token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was my error:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.hackerrank.com/x/api/v2/tests?duration=-1&access_token=123", options)
```

URL: ""

I had to add 'https://', for a while I used 'http' and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

They call it a permanent OAuth token in their documentation (linked from your comments), but the way they use it is very simple and not like the OAuth implementations I've worked with in the past.

You don't need to include the access token in your headers, simply append &access_token=[your token] to the URL (`"linkhere"`) of your request.

Example:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("www.hackerrank.com/x/api/v2/tests?duration=-1&access_token=123", options)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result.  I get a response code "200", but the action (inviting users to a test) is still not performed.  When I run the same request in POSTMAN or their api tools, it works, invitations are sent.  Is this a bug in urlFetchApp?

Comment: I doubt it's a bug in UrlFetchApp, I have hundreds of scripts using it to access various APIs without issue.  There is something different about the requests you are generating with Apps Script VS the other tools.  To rule out access token issues, try one of their simple GET requests and make sure you get the appropriate data back.  Once you have that working, strip down your PAYLOAD to the minimum for this post, particularly make sure you get rid of muteHttpExceptions and ContentType since they shouldn't be there.

Comment: Great advice! I believe the problem is it's not sending as a "POST" request. It looks like the response I am consistently getting is the response of a get request.  Does anyone have any ideas? I'm going to start with repositioning "method: POST" into my payload, etc.

Comment: In the Apps Script examples they put the property names "method", "payload" etc as quoted strings.  I wouldn't expect this to make a difference, but it might be worth a shot. Otherwise the way you are specifying a POST request looks correct.